# FirefoxDriver selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

Всем доброго дня, пытаюсь сделать программу на библиотек FirefoDriver, создал новый profile добавил. Но при запуске программы, когда программа доходит до  строчки

```
WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

она останавливаться
вот код:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("profileToolsQA");
d = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста код ошибки

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko , ошибки нету , просто программа останавливается при WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
и дальше не идёт

Comment: скорее всего проблема или с FirefoxDriver или с FirefoxProfile

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko , это как ? и что с этим делать ?

Comment: Попробуйте более тщательно проверить создаются ли эти объекты, я предлагаю дебагировать

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko при запуске через debug FireFox пишет:           Не удалось загрузить ваш профиль «Firefox». Возможно, он отсутствует или недоступен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Удалить из папки Extensions (в папке профиля) не ненужные дополнения(названия примерно вот такие {32ggfd71-3d4e-4522-84-77ggr6fda0b4d89}, если не помогает, то 2
2. Создать новый(чистый) профиль

в profiles.ini должно быть написано пример(путь до профиля windows7 %APPDATA%\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox):

```
[ProfileN]
Name=selenium
IsRelative=0
Path=D:\Selenium
```

а вызывать его нужно вот так:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium");
WebDriver driver = FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Имя профиля должно соответствовать имени где мы его вызываем

Comment: создал новый профиль , удалил всё из папки C:\Users\Андрей\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Extensions но ошибка та же : "Не удалось загрузить ваш профиль «Firefox». Возможно, он отсутствует или недоступен.". Но я обнаружил то что в папке с профилем нету файла profiles.ini, может всё ошибки из-за этого?

Comment: @as1andrey1 да из-за этого

Comment: файл я нашёл(не туда смотрел), всё правильно я пишу

Comment: @as1andrey1 можете показать что написано в profiles.ini?

Comment: [General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/nahd6ha2.default

[Profile1]
Name=user
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/t6iboeiu.user

[Profile2]
Name=profileToolsQA
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/mmqrroxe.profileToolsQA
Default=0

Comment: у меня window 10, это может вызывать ошибку ?

Comment: @as1andrey1 теоретически да, попробуйте обновить все до последней версии и скачать все обновления